# Error al usar websockets en angular

Tags: angular, websocket

Hola quiero conectarme a un socket que hice en adonis y quiero conectarme con angular, para esto instale la librería del cliente con el comando

```
npm i @adonisjs/websocket-client
```

y realizo la importación y todo bien

```
import Ws from '@adonisjs/websocket-client';
```

solo que al hacer la conexión al socket no me marca error en la pagina, esta es la función donde hago la conexión

```
this.ws = Ws("ws://localhost:3333"); //ruta de mi web socket
this.ws.connect(); //me conecto al ws
this.chat = this.ws.subscribe("wstemp") //subscribo al canal

this.chat.on("message", (data:any) =>{//recibir mensajes que están mandado otros clientes
  this.temperatura = data
})
```

y este es el error que me marca en la pagina al inspeccionarla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta con https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined

Comment: Gracias, ya lo hice pero aun persiste el error